# GraalVm with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, graalvm

Can I run spring mvc project with graalvm?

**(Spring MVC project and not Spring Boot)**

If Yes:
Is there any performance improvement?
(Any spring mvc example with graalvm would be helpful.)

If No:
why?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run Spring MVC applications with GraalVM. Here's a question that has more details about Spring and GraalVM: [GraalVM and Spring Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50911552/graalvm-and-spring-applications/51154446#51154446)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that article. But All Examples I come across are based on Spring boot and not Spring MVC (that is old spring mvc with manual configuration) and also the packaging of spring boot is JAR which can be passed to native image for conversion but spring mvc packaging is WAR.

Comment: Right, sorry, indeed you're right. you can run your war packaged Spring MVC application on GraalVM, just as any other application running on Java 8. The performance impact depends on your codebase, workload, hardware, etc.

Comment: Check spring-graalvm-native